# Formatting JSON inside PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to customize a hosted payment page and am having trouble with the JSON formatting. Essentially here is the information I have in JSON that needs to be customized:

```
{
    "id": "hosted_payment_page_id",
    "stylesheet_url": "https://127.0.0.1/css/payform.css",
    "field_configuration": {
        
        "body": {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": "transaction_amount",
                    "label": "Amount",
                    "value": "25.00"
                }
                
            ]
        },
    },
    "redirect_url_on_approve": "https://www.google.com",
    "redirect_url_on_decline": "https://www.bing.com",
    "redirect_url_delay": "15",
    "parent_send_message": 0,
    "hide_optional_fields": 0
}
```

In order to customize I need to encrypt it so I have this code below:

```
<?php

// Your HPP Encryption key
$encryptionKey = 'hpp_encryption_key';

// Convert to JSON string
$data = json_encode([
    'id' => '11e8052891d6420cb7a5ca18', 
    'redirect_url_on_approve' => 'https://some.full.url',
    'min_payment_amount' => '10',
    'max_payment_amount' => '20'
]);

$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8);
$salted = '';
$dx = '';
while (strlen($salted) < 48) {
    $dx = md5($dx . $encryptionKey . $salt, true);
    $salted .= $dx;
}
$key = substr($salted, 0, 32);
$iv = substr($salted, 32, 16);

// Encrypt the JSON object
$encryptedString = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);

$encodedEncryptedString =  urlencode(base64_encode("Salted__" . $salt . $encryptedString));

echo "https://{{sandbox_url}}/hostedpaymentpage?id={{hosted_payment_page_id}}&data=$encodedEncryptedString\n";
```

My question is how do I format the Field Configuration section of the JSON:

```
 "field_configuration": {
        
        "body": {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": "transaction_amount",
                    "label": "Amount",
                    "value": "25.00"
                }
                
            ]
        },
    },
```

So that it will work inside this portion of the PHP code?

```
$data = json_encode([
    'id' => '11e8052891d6420cb7a5ca18', 
    'redirect_url_on_approve' => 'https://some.full.url',
    'min_payment_amount' => '10',
    'max_payment_amount' => '20'
]);
```

Every time I try to format it it doesnt work and gives me a code error and Im just not sure how its being formatted improperly. It keeps telling me it expected ]. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Just add nested arrays. Associative arrays for the JSON objects, and ordinary arrays for the JSON arrays.

```
$data = json_encode([
    'id' => '11e8052891d6420cb7a5ca18', 
    'redirect_url_on_approve' => 'https://some.full.url',
    'min_payment_amount' => '10',
    'max_payment_amount' => '20',
    'field_configuration' => [
        'body' => [
            'fields' => [
                [
                    'id' => 'transaction_amount',
                    'label' => 'Amount',
                    'value' => '25.00'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```